# tomcat restart timeout when loading big file

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, web

When deploying web application on tomcat, I got error like as "tomcat restart timeout". This error is resulted from that the main thread will load and parse a big file which is time consumed when deploying. Some one suggests to use another thread to load and parse this file. But if the main thread is in use while the big file is still in loading, it will cause problems because the main thread can not accept request when the big file is not ready. So, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually,Once I ran into the same issue. But when I right clicks on Tomcat server on Eclipse’s Server tab, selecting ‘Open’, it opens ‘Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost’ page at Editor place, taking look at right side ‘Timeouts’ section, it says ‘Specify the time limit to complete server operations.’, default start (in seconds) is ’45’ seconds, you can change to 100 seconds or 10 mins, as you like.. That worked for me.

I hope it would solve your issue.